# Is there a way to bold a word within a Material-UI Typography element within a Card without a shift on render?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to bold a single word within a React Material-UI `<Typography>` element (which also is within a Material-UI `<Card>`). I was just using html tags, and it works:

```js
<Typography><b>First thing:</b> {answers[2]}</Typography>
```

But when I use them, they produce a visible re-sizing of the text on load.

I'm left nesting `<Typography>` tags, which forces me to apply a bunch of styling to make them appear normally:

```js
<Typography style={{display:'inline-flex', alignItems: 'baseline'}}><Typography variant='h6' style={{marginRight:'3px'}}>Path:</Typography> {path}</Typography>
```

This seems like a janky solution. Am I missing something? Like another reason why the `<b>` tags are causing a load delay, or a built-in Material-UI solution?

Full code for the `<Card>`, as reference:

```js
<Card className={classes.card}>
<CardActionArea>
 <RenderImage imageAddress={myImage} widthAndHeight={[230, 180]} style={{marginLeft: '10%'}} />
 <CardContent>
   <Typography style={{display:'inline-flex', alignItems: 'baseline'}}><Typography variant='h6' style={{marginRight:'3px'}}>Path:</Typography> {path}</Typography>
   <Typography><b>First thing:</b> {answers[2]}</Typography>
   <Typography><b>Second thing:</b> {answers[0]}</Typography>
   <Typography style={{marginBottom: 0}}><b>Third thing:</b> {answers[1]}</Typography>
 </CardContent>
 </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Comment: I'm using the <b> tag and there's no visible reload, perhaps this solution is still viable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you tried with `Box` component?

You could do something like

```js
<Typography component='div'>Normal text <Box fontWeight='fontWeightMedium' display='inline'>medium font weight text</Box> and some more normal text</Typography>
```

Note that `component='div'` prop on `Typography` wrapper is required as `Box` component cannot be nested under the Typography's default `p`.

Source [Typography font weight](https://material-ui.com/system/typography/#FontWeight.js)

Comment: This creates a waring  <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.

Comment: hey @MohamedDaher could you share a snippet of your code? Is it possible that you  added this Typography div component inside a <p> tag?

Comment: Well i dont have it anymore but i fixed what i wanted by simply adding a <b> </b> into Typography and it worked like charm. Thx for checking, appreciated!

Comment: as of Material-ui v4.11.4 creates an error (not a warning) in console, <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Comment: @PathToLife could you please share an example? Are you sure you don't have this Typography <div> component inside another Typography <p> component?

Comment: Sorry I had missed the component='div' prop! I do apologize, thank you for the comment. Editing now to unlock voting.

Comment: @PathToLife No problem! Edited now :)

Comment: div is not the correct semantic element for Text.

Answer (score 16):

To fix the issue Mohamed mentioned, you can change the component `Box` renders as to `span` (`displayInline` will be unnecessary using this method):

```
<Typography>Normal text <Box component="span" fontWeight='fontWeightMedium'>medium font weight text</Box> and some more normal text</Typography>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also do something like this:

```
<Typography>normal text <strong>bold text</strong> normal text</Typography>
```

Comment: You could, but any theming provided by MUI would be ignored.  Same reason you would want to avoid `<b>` and other html tags